# How to invoke script-module cmdlet from a binary cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module

I am writing a Powershell cmdlet in C# by inheriting from `PSCmdlet`. This is part of a powershell module which contains both binary and script components.

I want to be able to invoke a script module cmdlet from within my binary cmdlet.

I've worked out that inheriting from `PSCmdlet` gives me access to a lot more of Powershell's guts, and I have looked specifically at `InvokeCommand.GetCmdlet()` and `InvokeCommand.GetCommand()` but these both seem to return CommandInfo objects which don't appear to have a method to invoke them.

Am I supposed to call `InvokeCommand.InvokeScript()` to call my cmdlets? If so how/are `CommandInfo` objects supposed to be used to help?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm t rying to use `InvokeCommand.InvokeScript` without luck:

`var text = this.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(@"Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Out-String", false, PipelineResultTypes.None, _psObjects, null);`

`text` is `[0]: {}` when run, even though `_psObjects` has 10 items in it.

Answer (score 0):

Likely `InvokeScript` is what you want because you want to execute a script. Now, you likely had issues because you would use it more like

```cs
InvokeCommand.InvokeScript("Get-MyCmdlet -ParameterName value");
```

That being said, the real answer to your question is that you need a `PowerShell` object that represents the interpreter.

```cs
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand(InvokeCommand.GetCmdlet("Get-MyCmdlet"));
ps.AddParameter("ParameterName", "value");

var output = ps.Invoke();
```

The interpreter uses `CommandInfo` (and `AddCommand` has an overload with a `string` that under-the-hood would create one) for its Reflection work to interpret whatever you want.